# Area51 typo for "launching very soon" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, user-interface

> This site is nearing the end of its beta will be launching very soon.

...as seen [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming) should become:

> This site is nearing the end of its beta **and** will be launching very soon.

Comment: ... I picture Jeff going [to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant `&`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) :)

Comment: @KennyTM: I'm totally surprised it doesn't say *"This site **are** nearing the end of its beta and will be launching very soon."*

Comment: @Kenny I don't think that string is actually the result of a concatenation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. Thanks for the report.